# WAV file not working. How can I fix it?

Tags: audio, wav, recording

I have this file which came form a cellphone company's call center. It's supposed to be a recording of a conversation I had with them. I tried to open it using Windows Media Player, VLC Media Player, and Audacity. But it didn't work.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

## Here's all the text that came in the email with the file:

```
If you are having difficulty playing the attached multimedia file(s) using Windows Media Player, contact your technical support representative


------------ Segment-related information -------------

Contact ID = 9120617573350001032
Start Time = 14/07/2014 10:02:13
Local Start Time = 14/07/2014 10:02:13
End Time = 14/07/2014 10:16:11
Local End Time = 14/07/2014 10:16:11
Extension = 11134
Agent = שלו, מלי
PBX ID = 11134
Duration = 00:13:58
Dialed From (ANI) = 11134          
Dialed To (DNIS) = 0545920155     
Remarked On =
Remarked By =
Remark =
Acquisition Module = 17
Channel = 286
Screen Acquisition Module = 14
With Screens = 1
Direction = 2
Switch Call Id = 2144221398988751
WrapUp Time = 00:00:34
Switch Name = Cosmocom2
Custom Data 1 = 1
Custom Data 2 = 10.91.12.53
Custom Data 3 = 11134:10.19.221.155:6815 Custom Data 4 = 2144221398988751000 Custom Data 5 = שירות חול Custom Data 6 = 0545920155 Custom Data 7 = XEN16113 Custom Data 8 = Custom Data 9 = חול חבילות Custom Data 10 = 4806591 Custom Data 11 = Custom Data 12 = Custom Data 13 = Custom Data 14 = Custom Data 15 = Custom Data 16 = Custom Data 17 = Custom Data 18 = Custom Data 19 = Custom Data 20 = Custom Data 21 = Custom Data 22 = Custom Data 23 = Custom Data 24 = Custom Data 25 = Custom Data 26 = Custom Data 27 = Custom Data 28 = Custom Data 29 = Custom Data 30 = Custom Data 31 = Custom Data 32 = Custom Data 33 = Custom Data 34 = Custom Data 35 = Custom Data 36 = Custom Data 37 = Custom Data 38 = Custom Data 39 = Custom Data 40 = Custom Data 41 = Custom Data 42 = Custom Data 43 = Custom Data 44 = Custom Data 45 = Custom Data 46 = Custom Data 47 = Custom Data 48 = Custom Data 49 = Custom Data 50 = Custom Data 51 = Custom Data 52 = Custom Data 53 = Custom Data 54 = Custom Data 55 = Custom Data 56 = Custom Data 57 = Custom Data 58 = Custom Data 59 = Custom Data 60 = Custom Data 61 = Custom Data 62 = Custom Data 63 = Custom Data 64 = Custom Data 65 = Custom Data 66 = Custom Data 67 = Custom Data 68 = Custom Data 69 = Custom Data 70 = Custom Data 71 = Custom Data 72 = Custom Data 73 = Custom Data 74 = Attached file name: AudioOnly_Site_01_AudioModule_17_AudioChannel_286_14-Jul-2014_07.02.13.500.WAV
```

===

And here's a link to the file itself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1r5xyHzGXL9Rl8td2dQdXFlU3puVWZ5aXFCcUZ4V3h2UmE4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

According to the `fmt` chunk in the WAV header, the audio data is encoded using a format named `WAVE_FORMAT_VOICEAGE_AMR_WB` from [VoiceAge Corporation](http://www.voiceage.com).  That is not a commonly used format on desktops, but is more commonly used in mobile devices.  You need to install an audio codec that supports that format, or else you should ask the call center to convert their WAV file into a more common desktop format, like PCM or GSM 6.10.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I might download a codec that supports it?

Comment: I don't know.  You will have to look around. Or contact VoiceAge directly.  I tried a third party [AMR Player](http://www.amrplayer.com), but it could not play the audio either, I even tried its WAV->AMR convertor, and even stripping off the WAV header from the file.